# getParcelableExtra return null NFC Tag

Tags: java, android, nfc

I know this is a redundant question on StackOverflow but I tried a lot of the answers I've found and none of them worked. I'd like to send a message when I press a button but when I call my nfc writing function in a Fragment, but I've put the NDEF_Discovered in the AndroidManifest.xml. The `intent.getParcelableExtra( NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG )` returns null and I can't find out why. Here's my code :

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<activity
    android:name="com.iiil.cccdm.ebar.gui.activity.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TAG_DISCOVERED"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>

        <data android:mimeType="text/*"/>
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

#### ConsommerFragment (in onCreateView())

```
View rootView = inflater.inflate( R.layout.consommer_fragment, container, false );
ImageButton btn = (ImageButton) rootView.findViewById( R.id.drinkButton );
btn.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick( View v ) {
        Toast.makeText( getActivity(), "in listener", Toast.LENGTH_LONG );
                // Recupération de l'id
                UserData userData = new UserData( getActivity() );
                Integer idUser = userData.getId();

                Intent intent = this.getActivity().getIntent();
                if ( intent == null ) {
                    Log.e( this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "INTENT NULL" );
                }

                NFCTransfer nfcTransfer = NFCTransfer.getInstance( getActivity() );
                // TODO : Test avec Yohan et améliorer.
                nfcTransfer.writeToDevice( idUser.toString(), intent );
    }
} );
```

#### NFCTransfer

```
public void writeToDevice( String msgToWrite, Intent intent ) {
    Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra( NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG );
    if ( tag == null ) {
        Log.e(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "tag == null");
        Toast.makeText( context, "No Tag. Waiting...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG )
             .show();
        return;
    }

    Ndef ndefref = Ndef.get( tag );
    /* ... the rest of the function is useless since tag is null*/
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't described how you want your application to handle working with NFC cards, as there are several possible scenarios:

1. When the application is not started and you swipe a NFC card, your application starts.
   If this is what you want, you will receive the proper intent in your activity's onCreate() method.

From the info you've provided it looks like you should probably also listen for a TECH_DISCOVERED intent and add a tech list meta-data block to your AndroidManifest.xml, like this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED" />
</intent-filter>
<meta-data
        android:name="android.nfc.action.TECH_DISCOVERED"
        android:resource="@xml/nfc_tech_filter" />
```

Also, see [this](https://developer.android.com/samples/CardReader/res/xml/nfc_tech_filter.html) for a sample tech list (i.e. what types of NFC tech should your app handle).

2. Your app is already running in the foreground when you scan a NFC tag.
   In this case you should override the onNewIntent() method in your activity in order to receive the proper intent, and then handle your operations there.

_

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag nfcTag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    if (nfcTag == null) {
        Log.w(LOG_TAG, "Unable to obtain NFC tag from intent!");
    } else {
        String tagId = bytesToHex(nfcTag.getId());
        ...
    }
```

Also, note that you can use the [foreground dispatch system](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc.html#foreground-dispatch) in order to register/unregister listening for NFC intents directly from your activity code, instead of setting up the configuration in your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Sorry if I made myself unclear. The fact is that I want to send a nfc message when I press my button. I don't want to read any message with it, using the `NDef` method `writeNdefMessage`.

Comment: Well yes, but before you can write the message, your app should first "see" the NFC card, and it does it after it receives the respective intents.

Comment: First thing you'd want to check is determine the exact type of your NFC card. If it's NDEF, then the NDEF_DISCOVERED intent will suffice, otherwise you should also listen for TECH_DISCOVERED intent and provide a corresponding tech list xml.

Comment: To determine the type of your NFC card, you could install [NFC TagInfo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo), then swipe your NFC card and check out the card type info and the list of supported tech classes.

Comment: We only need NDEF (thanks to NFC TagInfo). The card is in fact a RasperryPi expansion card [link](http://fr.farnell.com/nxp/explore-nfc/carte-add-on-nfc-pour-raspberry/dp/2366201)

Comment: So, is your application launched when you put the card to your device?

Comment: If not, then your card may be Non-NDEF Formatted, and as per [this diagram](http://developer.android.com/images/nfc_tag_dispatch.png) it should be handled by the TECH_DISCOVERED intent and tech list.

Comment: If you get stuck, just attach the list of supported tech classes you got from the NFC TagInfo app to your question, and I'll take a look tomorrow morning.

Comment: Well.. I didn't knew that we had to put the phone on the device BEFORE pressing the button... Thank's a lot !